# How do I arrange Items in a List-box?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox, controls, form-control

I am working on a VB WindowsForms Application. The form has a listbox which contains numbers a its **Items**. They are not arranged into Numeric sequence like..

```
01
09
02
07
...
```

I Want to arrange them Into a Numeric sequence such as..

```
01
02
07
09
...
```

I have not got any idea for doing so.

Thank you

Comment: Is your listbox databound?

Comment: no! not a databound listbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this method and call the sort function...

```
Private Sub SortListBox(ByVal listBox As ListBox)
Dim TempList As New List(Of Integer)
For Each LI In listBox.Items
    TempList.Add(Integer.Parse(LI.ToString()))
Next
TempList.Sort()
listBox.DataSource = TempList
End Sub
```

Then just call it after you have added all your items...

```
 SortListBox(ListBox1)
```

Answer (score 0):

to sort it you will need to call `ListBox1.Sorted = true`

Comment: According to 'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sorted(v=vs.110).aspx': "A ListBox with its Sorted set to true should not be bound to data using the DataSource property. To display sorted data in a bound ListBox, you should bind to a data source that supports sorting and have the data source provide the sorting."